# Oracle systimestamp in query condition in different timezone

Tags: oracle, jdbc, timestamp, timezone

I have the following code using column `lock_until TIMESTAMP(3)`. The code inserts `systimestamp + 5 minutes` and then selects all rows with `lock_until < systimestamp`. I would expect no rows in the result set that since the `lock_until` is in the future but the row is returned. The most likely reason is that my local timezone is UTC+2 but I do not see how is this possible. The code works as expected with `current_timestamp` but I would prefer the code be client timezone neutral.

```
jdbcTemplate.update("delete from shedlock where name = 'test'");
System.out.println(jdbcTemplate.queryForList("SELECT SESSIONTIMEZONE FROM dual"));
// insert, lock_until is now + 5 minutes
jdbcTemplate.update("INSERT INTO shedlock(name, lock_until, locked_at, locked_by) VALUES('test', systimestamp + 5/(24 * 60), systimestamp, 'me')");
// select if lock_until <= systimestamp
System.out.println(jdbcTemplate.queryForList("select * from shedlock where lock_until <= systimestamp"));
// systimestamp ?
System.out.println(jdbcTemplate.queryForList("select systimestamp from dual"));
```

results in

```
Local time: 17:32:48.872
[{SESSIONTIMEZONE=Europe/Prague}]
[{NAME=test, LOCK_UNTIL=2020-04-25 15:37:49.0, LOCKED_AT=2020-04-25 15:32:49.106, LOCKED_BY=me}]
[{SYSTIMESTAMP=2020-04-25 17:32:49.168954}]
```

Comment: Do you get the same issue if you run the same statements directly in the database? If so, then it is nothing to do with JDBC and is probably to do with different time zones.

Comment: What does `SELECT TO_CHAR( systimestamp, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF9 TZR' ) FROM DUAL` output? My bet is that is doesn't end with `Europe/Prague`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions173.htm):

> `SYSTIMESTAMP` returns the system date, including fractional seconds and time zone, of the system on which the database resides. The return type is `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`.

When you do:

```sql
INSERT INTO shedlock (
  name,
  lock_until,
  locked_at,
  locked_by
) VALUES (
  'test',
  systimestamp + 5/(24 * 60),
  systimestamp,
  'me'
)
```

It is implicitly doing:

```
INSERT INTO shedlock (
  name,
  lock_until,
  locked_at,
  locked_by
) VALUES (
  'test',
  CAST( systimestamp + 5/(24 * 60) AS TIMESTAMP(3) ),
  CAST( systimestamp AS TIMESTAMP(3) ),
  'me'
)
```

Which will discard the time zone information and keep the other date/time components as-is.

However, when you do the `SELECT` it is implicitly doing:

```sql
select *
from   shedlock
where  FROM_TZ( lock_until, SESSIONTIMEZONE ) <= systimestamp
```

and adding the session time zone to the stored value and then comparing it to a timestamp with the time zone of the system on which the database resides; if these two time zones are not the same then you will get rows being unexpectedly included/excluded.

What you could instead do is explicitly cast `SYSTIMESTAMP` from a `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` data type to a `TIMESTAMP` data type:

```sql
select *
from   shedlock
where  lock_until <= CAST( systimestamp AS TIMESTAMP(3) )
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=74ee8b937a5a0ef8eca411b93a246f53)

Comment: Thanks, it makes sense. Related answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/42274119/277042